# Using :init in use-package produces an error-like message

Tags: use-package

My .emacs file contains

(use-package mds
:commands mds mds-version
:init (mds))

That produces, in *Messages*, (Shell command failed with code 1 and no output).

If :init is replaced with :config that message is not produced.   Any suggestions on how to debug this?  Replacing the definition of the mds function with a version that does nothing doesn't help, the behavior doesn't change, i.e. message is produced with :init but not :config.

Answer (score 1):

Commands in `:init` is evaluated `before` the package is loaded.

That's why `(mds)` failed because `mds` has not been loaded when it is called.

You generally use `:init` to configure some variables the package will use when loading.

You should use `:config` if you want to call `(mds)` at the exact time you load the package.

Documentation for `use-package`

```
:init            Code to run before PACKAGE-NAME has been loaded.
:config          Code to run after PACKAGE-NAME has been loaded.  Note that
                 if loading is deferred for any reason, this code does not
                 execute until the lazy load has occurred.
```

Comment: Thanks.  While using :config (mds) works, am still seeing, in the *Messages* buffer, after running mds, the message "(Shell command failed with code 1 and no output)".  Maybe it's benign, but I'd like to know what is generating that message.  Haven't a clue how to figure that out.  It isn't caused by mds, which I confirmed by temporarily rewriting mds to do nothing; the same messages appears.

Comment: You can turn on debugger by `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, and run that command again to see the trace.

Comment: Have tried that with no help.  Am currently using 
(use-package mds
  :commands mds mds-version
  :config (mds) (message "Finished loading mds"))
After starting emacs, nothing of significance appears in the *Messages* buffer until I executed mds, then see
(Shell command failed with code 1 and no output)
Resuming loading Maple Debugger Server
Finished loading Maple Debugger Server
Executing toggle-debug-on-error either before or after this, and then executing mds, does nothing.  Cannot debug the cause.  The message seems benign, but annoying.

Comment: Can you share the content of `mds`? It looks like not on melpa/elpa.

Comment: The package is available on github, https://github.com/JoeRiel/mdcs.  That's somewhat older, and appears to have some byte-compilation issues, but I was able to use it to replace my existing package and see the same issue.  The git name is actually mdcs; it supplies both a client (mdc, written in Maple) and a server (mds, written in elisp).  The tool is for debugging Maple procedures.  Suspect you only need the lisp part to see the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/JoeRiel/mdcs/blob/master/lisp/mds.el#L62

Do you have `wmctrl` installed?

Comment: Thanks.  Don't recall when I updated to Debian 11, but suspect wmctrl went away at that time.  The code checks for wmctrl and so works around it missing, but I didn't realize that the check, which fails, causes the message to be written to the *Messages* buffer.  Will fix that.  Appreciate the help.